# Unable to set selected in symfony 2 twig file

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a form where the dropdown value is coming from another entity.

```
->add('country', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Country',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.countryName', 'ASC');
                },
                'empty_value' => 'Select Country',
                'required' => true,
                'mapped' => true,
                'class' => 'BundleAdminBundle:KidsKulaCountry',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control sml-frm'),
                //...
            ))
```

In the twig file i want to set selected the value at edit.

```
{{ form_widget(form.country, {value: Setcountry } ) }}
```

if I print

> {{Setcountry}}

its returns result but it does not set selected.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your Setcountry is the *id* of the entity you want to select. You can do this with the conversion of the Setcountry of ***int*** to ***string*** in the next way:

```
{{ form_widget(form.country, {value: Setcountry ~ "" } ) }}
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please, tick the question as correct to help other people to see this as a right answer. Thank you.